# WCF Operation not supported in WCF Test Client because it uses type system.object[]

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

Checking Visual studio cmd and its giving WCF Operation not supported in WCF Test Client because it uses type system.object[]

```
public object[] getAllClientApps(string client_name)
            {
                object[] msg = new object[2];
                try
                {
                    string sql = @"  SELECT [application]
    FROM #portal.[dbo].[ix_clientApplications] inner join #portal.[dbo].[ix_clients] on #portal.[dbo].[ix_clientApplications].clientID
    = #portal.[dbo].[ix_clients].client_id Where #portal.[dbo].[ix_clients].client_name='{client_name}' and #portal.[dbo].[ix_clientApplications].application not in('sys','dev','gsa') 
     and #portal.[dbo].[ix_clientApplications].updateAvailable=1 ; 

    SELECT [clientId], appName, [licenseType]
    ,[licenseExpiry]
    ,[isExpired]
    ,[machineId]
    ,[svr_appCustomJson]
    FROM #portal.[dbo].[ix_licensedClientApps] where clientId=( select client_id from [inxPortalV4].[dbo].[ix_clients] where client_name='{client_name}')

    ";
                    sql = tools.getQueryWithDbName(sql);
                    sql = sql.Replace("{client_name}", client_name);
                    System.Data.DataSet dsData = dbUtil.ReadDataSet(sql);

                    string arrClntApps = inx.portal.common.tools.table2Json(dsData, 0);
                    string arrClntNewAppsData = inx.portal.common.tools.table2Json(dsData, 1);
                    msg[0] = arrClntApps;
                    msg[1] = arrClntNewAppsData;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw (new Exception("" + e));
                }
                return msg;
            }
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Generally using "object" and "object[]" (etc) on this type of interface is simply: not a good idea... I suggest: don't do that. Return and accept data of a known type.

Comment: Your `catch` block is _evil_.

Comment: Same query is explained at 
                                                                 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856128/this-operation-is-not-supported-in-the-wcf-test-client-because-it-uses-type-syst

Comment: @MarcGravell : what can i use instead of object ?

Comment: @Rahul the thing you're sending. If you're sending orders, `Order[]`, etc