# Operation Contract not working with WCF Test Client

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services, wcf-client

i am getting an error

```
this operation is not supported in wcf test client because it uses system.object
```

Heres my code screenshot for IService.cs:
[image]

heres my screenshot for reference.cs
[image]

but still i am getting this error ::
[image]

Comment: I don't know what causes the errors but it seems ugly how you pass those parameters to your method. If it was me I will create a class or a structure at least which will decorated with DataCOntract and DataMember attributes. The class or structure will expose as properties the parameters you pass to your actual function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this operation is not supported in the wcf test client because it uses type system.object\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856128/this-operation-is-not-supported-in-the-wcf-test-client-because-it-uses-type-syst)

Comment: The WCF test client simply can't handle arbitrary objects, and neither can WCF itself. It is only that you would get an error during runtime, depending if the types inside your object array actually turn out to be serializable or not (also see the KnownTypesAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

*I don't think you can expose generic object in WCF service because server/client would not know how to deserialize your data.
You have to expose a definite class with [DataContract] attribute. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx*

---- EDIT
Sorry, I was wrong. Don't worry. It's just not working with the WCF test client. Just write a simple console client to test it.

Comment: i am having few more operations having the same way wroking.But i am getting warning for this operation only and the warning seems not related

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Don't worry. It's just not working with the WCF test client. Just write a simple console client to test it.